# How to use a c++ timer so that the functions i want to execute executes when a certain time has come?

Tags: c++, timer, c++-chrono

Basically my goal is to call a function when a certain time has come, i have tried something like this but it doesnt work:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono> 
#include <iostream>


class Timer
{
private:

    using clock_type = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using second_type = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1> >;

    std::chrono::time_point<clock_type> m_beg{ clock_type::now() };

public:

    void reset()
    {
        m_beg = clock_type::now();
    }

    double elapsed() const
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<second_type>(clock_type::now() - m_beg).count();
    }
};

int main()
{
    
    Timer t;
    while (true)
    {
        double time{ 1.00 };
        std::cout << "Time taken: " << t.elapsed() << " seconds\n";
        if (t.elapsed() == time)
        {
            //call some random func
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas on why this doesnt work and are there any better ways to do this?

for example my goal is to execute func1 at time 13.4 execute func2 at time 16.5 and so on..

Os: Win10 64bit

Comment: Have you tried [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until)  and then calling your random func? Also, `t.elapsed() == time` is doomed. `t.elapsed() >= time` would be more appropriate, but you reset `time` every loop so... no, that's not good either.

Comment: I cant use sleep because of the fact that the thread execution stops and that doesnt meet what i want, i have to use a timer for this and not stop thread execution.

Comment: There are no timers afaik. If you want that, you'll need to start a thread that sleeps and fires upon timeout.

Comment: Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
std::thread timer([]() {
  std::this_thread::sleep_until(<your target time>);
  // call your "random" function
});
```

You can also use Win32 API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer, but I don't see how it will be easier...

Comment: Note that if the "random" function uses resources shared with the main thread you'll have to take steps to prevent the sundry bits of nastiness that can result. You may be better off sending a message back to the main thread that the main thread can take action on.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree; however, there is nothing that can handle messages in the OP's question...

Comment: Yeah. Ain't non-sequential code a <expletive deleted>?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows, so long as your program has a message loop and is actively pumping messages then you can simply do:

```
SetTimer (NULL, 0, time_to_wait_for, MyTimerProc);
```

Where `MyTimerProc` would look something like this:

```
void CALLBACK MyTimerProc (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR timer_id, DWORD elapsed)
{
    KillTimer (hWnd, timer_id);
    // ... do whatever it is you wanted to do after time_to_wait_for
}
```

There's a link to the documentation in Vlad's answer.  `time_to_wait_for` is specified in milliseconds.